# How does one prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{d/2}\log\frac{1-e^{-\beta(x-\mu)(n+1)}}{1-e^{-\beta(x-\mu)}} = 0$?

Tags: limits

How would one go about proving
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{d/2}\log\frac{1-e^{-\beta(x-\mu)(n+1)}}{1-e^{-\beta(x-\mu)}} = 0
\end{equation}

where $n, d\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R^+}, \mu\in\mathbb{R}$? If this does not hold, will putting any bounds on $d, n,$ and/or $\mu$ make the limit hold?

While I tried using L'Hospital, I couldn't get anything using that.

PS: This limit came from a Stat Mech calculation on Ideal Quantum Gases which the textbook skipped, if anyone was interested where this came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have for $n\ge 1$

$$\begin{align}
\log\left(\frac{1-e^{-\beta(n+1)(x-\mu)}}{1-e^{-\beta(x-\mu)}}\right)&=\log\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-\beta k (x-\mu)}\right)
\end{align}$$

Using $\frac x{1+x}\le \log(1+x)\le x$, we find

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n x^{d/2}e^{-\beta k(x-\mu)}}{1+\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-\beta k(x-\mu)}}\le x^{d/2}\log\left(\frac{1-e^{-\beta(n+1)(x-\mu)}}{1-e^{-\beta(x-\mu)}}\right)\le \sum_{k=1}^n x^{d/2}e^{-\beta k(x-\mu)}$$

Now use the squeeze theorem.